FFmpeg audio stream selection error
[STREAM] index=0 codec_name=h264
[STREAM] index=1 codec_name=aac
[STREAM] index=2 codec_name=mp3

ffmpeg.exe  -y -i "C:\Temp\MultiAudio\Test0V1A2A.mkv" -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:2  -map_metadata -1 -metadata title="Test0V1A2A" -sn -dn -f MP4 -preset veryslow -crf 18 libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -maxrate 500k -minrate 450 -bufsize 1000k -vf scale=960:540 -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec:a:2 AAC -b:a 128k "C:\Temp\MultiAudio\Test0V1A2A.MP4" -loglevel error

Stream map '' matches no streams.
To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map.
Failed to set value '0:a:2' for option 'map': Invalid argument

I am at a loss why I cannot select the second audio stream using the above command line. Anyone see an obvious mistake ?
If I exclude the map section I get Stream 1 fine but when included it objects saying no 2 stream. I even downloaded the latest stable  Windows64 build with no resolution.
NB: With a MAP used its conversion speed goes from about 3x to 0.5x which is appalling.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

use -map 0:0 -map 0:2 or -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1

I want to use the second audio stream #2 in the output not #1 but whenever I try to 'map' I get "Stream map '' matches no streams." As we know it exists I can only assume a syntax &/or structure error in the command line. Been going round in circles so needed some fresh eyes to pull it apart :-)  Having read the documentation so many times I am thinking -map 0:a:1 is the second audio stream so -map 0:a:0 is the 1st audio stream and its not related to the index number just counting the types of stream. I had thought streams were absolute numbers!

That looked to work perfectly, thanks
